# How can I solve "No input file specified" error on IIS for URLs with a slash and content after the PHP file?

Tags: iis, php7

I am running a PHP 7.3 application on IIS using the FastCGI handler to execute the files. When requesting URLs which end on *.php in the browser, everything works fine.

However, some paths of the application look like this: `http://my-site.com/image.php/my_image_name.png`, i.e., there is some more content after the file name of the PHP file, which is not a query string. For these URLs, IIS always responds with HTTP 404 and the message "No input file specified."

How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse URLs like this, PHP scripts use path information provided by PHP. Using the FastCGI handler seems to mess up this path information. Luckily, PHP has a configuration option to fix these paths:

Navigate to your `php.ini` file and set the following option:

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
```

This is the setting recommended by Microsoft when hosting PHP applications on IIS: [Using FastCGI to Host PHP Applications on IIS 7](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis)